# what does this mean? literally

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me what this sentence means?

> "Do you think I should grow some hair just to pull it out with an order this low?"

This is an example of Rhetorical Questions in a book I am reading these days and there is no context for the question.

Answer (score 2):

That...is a very weird sentence. Still, let's have a go at it...

I *think* it's a reference to the idiom "Pulling one's hair out", indicating frustration, confusion, or other loss of temper. Examples:

> You kids are too loud! I'm **pulling my hair out** over here!
>
> We fixed the machines, you can stop **pulling your hair out**.
>
> When I was a kid, I always made my Mum **pull her hair out**.

So the first part of the sentence appears to be expressing frustration. By the sounds of it, a person who is either bald or has a very short haircut is frustrated, and is jokingly suggesting that they should **grow some hair** so that when frustrated they could **pull it out**.

"**Order this low**" is a bit more puzzling - it could mean a number of things. For our purposes, though, we can suppose it's some condition that causes distress to the speaker - perhaps it's a very small order for some product that requires a complicated set-up procedure to produce, thus the order is more trouble than it's worth.

Honestly, this sentence seems like it needs a lot of context to be clear; I would rephrase it like this:

> "**This order is** *annoyingly* **low**", said the bald manager. "**Do you think I should grow some hair so that I could** *express my anger by* **pulling it out**?"

Comment: Your formatting is messed up for the last blockquote.